# How to move an element in an array to a different index in C?

Tags: c

Let's say I have an array of scores `a[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`, how can I move `a[4]` to `a[0]` ?

The output should be `a[5]={5,1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10}`. Any tips would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Store the value at `a[4]` in a temporary variable. Move the rest of the entries, and then put the temporary variable into `a[0]`.

Comment: That's where I am confused. How exactly should I move the entries? because 6,7,8,9,10 never change their positions.

Comment: Useful link : http://www.codeforwin.in/2016/01/c-program-to-swap-first-and-last-digit-of-number.html

Comment: The loop that moves the values should start by moving `a[3]` to `a[4]`, and should end when it moves `a[0]` to `a[1]`. So the loop variable should count down from 3 to 0.

Answer (score 2):

Array will not fill up the gap by itself, you have to move them yourself, so these are the steps:

Assuming you starts with an array with the following values:

```
+-----------------------+
|10|20|30|40|50|60|70|80| and you want to move 80 to the first index..
+-----------------------+
```

1. Store the element you are interested to move to a temp variable.

   ```
   +-----------------------+
   |10|20|30|40|50|60|70|80|  myArray
   +-----------------------+
   +--+
   |80|  temp
   +--+
   ```
2. From the position of the candidate element (position of element to be moved), assign all previous values to their next position.

   ```
   +-----------------------+
   |10|10|20|30|40|50|60|70|  myArray
   +-----------------------+
   +--+
   |80|  temp
   +--+
   ```
3. Assign temp value to the element in the position where you are interested to move.

   ```
   +-----------------------+
   |80|10|20|30|40|50|60|70|  myArray
   +-----------------------+
   +--+
   |80|  temp
   +--+
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this:

1. Move the element at an index to the new position.
2. Shift the elements in between to the set position.

So, something like this should do the trick:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void move_and_shift(int array[], int index, int newIndex) {
    int temp = array[index];
    // Shift all of the elements between newIndex and index by 1.
    memmove(array + newIndex, array + newIndex + 1,
        sizeof(int) * abs(newIndex - index));
    array[newIndex] = temp;
    }
```